# Cons of sending content-available=true and content-priority=high in BULK FCM messages?

Tags: messaging, cloud, cdn

While sending FCMs, I've noticed these two headers are important(message won't go without these headers), but what could be the cons of sending both of these headers as it is? I tried to read about these content-negotiation headers but could not find any information about them in internet. The internet says that we need these headers only in iOS messages, but instead I required these for android messages notifications.

And are these headers location dependent? i.e only required if the location of transmitter and receiver is long?

---

GCM/FCM=Google Cloud Messaging/Firebase Cloud Messaging. A product used to send notification to android devices.

Articles found on internet:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77102069/why-is-gcm-and-apn-notifications-going-on-some-clients-and-not-on-others

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44846973/not-receiving-push-notifications-if-sending-data-but-notification-works-pa?rq=2

Comment: If you're talking about [GCM / FCM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebase_Cloud_Messaging) then please add a tag to your Question. If your WTF TLA is about something else, then please spell it out if you wish to convey the meaning of your sentence to humans who might read it. Rather than mumble about "internet says", please mention some particular URL that folks can go visit for context about this problem space.

Comment: Updated everything in post. Tell me if you wan some more!

Comment: Thank you for the clarity, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

> tried to read about these content-negotiation headers but could not find any information about them in internet.

I don't understand this remark.
Upon consulting the vendor's
[documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/firebase-admin.messaging.messagingoptions#messagingoptionscontentavailable)
a search for the header field, "content-available",
immediately reveals:

> On iOS, use this field to represent content-available in the APNs payload. When a notification or data message is sent and this is set to true, an inactive client app is awoken. On Android, data messages wake the app by default.

The value defaults to False,
so if you don't know what type of client you're sending to
and if you support any iOS users that use
the Apple Push Notification service,
you will likely want to set this flag.

Similarly the "content-priority"
[documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#setting-the-priority-of-a-message)
explains:

> You have two options for assigning delivery priority to downstream messages:
>
> - Normal priority. Normal priority messages are delivered immediately when the app is in the foreground. For backgrounded apps, delivery may be delayed. For less time-sensitive messages, such as notifications of new email, keeping your UI in sync, or syncing app data in the background, choose normal delivery priority.
> - High priority. FCM attempts to deliver high priority messages immediately even if the device is in Doze mode.

The vendor documentation seems fairly clear.
When serving heterogeneous client types,
the headers have orthogonal meanings.
The headers are not location dependent.
Supply one or both headers if they fit your application's use case.

If you found the documentation ambiguous or wrong,
definitely file a documentation bug with the vendor.

Comment: Why do I require content-available=true for android as well? Did something changed since android 13?

Comment: Sounds like the behavior changed in a way that the docs don't reflect. Definitely worth filing a documentation bug with the vendor.

Comment: Ok I'll email them.